# Link to multiple CSS files

Tags: html, css

So, I'm really new to development, but I have an assignment where I have to create a 3 page site. The thing is that the three pages share some things (header, footer, title, banner), and that's great, but there are differences in the rest of the content, so using only one CSS files requires a lod of ID's in the HTML. I was thinking that maybe I could use 1 CSS file for the elements all the pages share, and a different one for each of the pages. Right now I'm using individual CSS files for each page, but if I want to change the footer or header, I'll have to do it three times.
In case this is possible... is it a good practice?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is absolutely possible!

The same way you currently use the `<link>` element to reference the css for that given page.

The same way you can add multiple css files.

Now lets say you want to have one css file that takes care of all the styling shared in all pages like the header, footer etc. You can make a new `shared.css` file and reference it on all 3 pages In addition to the designated css file for that given page.

See example below:

**PAGE 1**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>My website</title> 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="page1.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shared.css" />
               
</head>                                 
<body>
</body>                              
</html>
```

**PAGE 2**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>My website</title> 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="page2.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shared.css" />
          
</head>                                 
<body>
</body>                            
</html>
```

**PAGE 3**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>My website</title> 

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="page3.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="shared.css" />
          
</head>                                 
<body>
</body>                            
</html>
```

Comment: Great! And in case I accidentally have the same rule in both files, which one is applied?

Answer (score 1):

You can keep the common rules of all the three  pages (the header, footer etc.) in a single css file to be shared by all the three pages. After it, you can make a separate css file for each page with different rules for the contents.

In short, you will have two css files for each page => One common file with common rules and one different file for page-specific rules.

Also, if you are not having very long rules (>500 lines), and less pages, you can keep all the rules in a single file. For your reference, you can separate the common rules and page-specific rules by comments like the example below:

```
/**********************Common rules***************************/
common rule 1{
    /*Something*/
}

common rule 2{
    /*Something*/
}

/***********************Page 1 rules***************************/
page1 rule 1{
    /*Something*/
}
```

Though this is not highly recommended, you can use any of these two methods as per your convenience.